# Castle Windsor and LifestyleBoundTo(scopeRootBinder)

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, castle

I cant find any examples of using scopeRootBinder. I'm not sure if it can help me. Here's the problem(test). I need that each instance of ChildService gets build with its own instance of Component2.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CastleContainer_ChildServices_GetItsOwnObject()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<IRootService>().ImplementedBy<RootService>().LifestyleTransient()
                .DependsOn(ServiceOverride.ForKey("childServices")
                                                     .Eq("ChildService", "ChildService")));
        container.Register(Component.For<IChildService>().ImplementedBy<ChildService>().LifestyleTransient().Named("ChildService"));
        //nearest in 3.2 container.Register(Component.For<Component2>().ImplementedBy<Component2>().LifestyleBoundToNearest<IChildService>());
        //creates single instance of Component2 container.Register(Component.For<Component2>().ImplementedBy<Component2>().LifestyleBoundTo<ChildService>());

        Func<IHandler[], IHandler> scopeRootBinder = ScopeRootBinder;
        container.Register(Component.For<Component2>().ImplementedBy<Component2>().LifestyleBoundTo(scopeRootBinder));
        container.Register(Component.For<Component3>().ImplementedBy<Component3>().LifestyleTransient());

        var rs = container.Resolve<IRootService>();
        var first = rs.ChildServices[0];
        var second = rs.ChildServices[1];
        ReferenceEquals(first, second).Should().BeFalse();
        ReferenceEquals(first.Component2, second.Component2).Should().BeFalse("each child service should have its own Component2");
        ReferenceEquals(first.Component2, first.Component3.Component2).Should().BeTrue();
        ReferenceEquals(second.Component2, second.Component3.Component2).Should().BeTrue();
    }
    private IHandler ScopeRootBinder(IHandler[] handlers)
    {
        //not clear what should be here???
        var r = handlers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.ComponentModel.Services.Any(t => t.Name == "IChildService"));
        return r;
    }
```

and here're the classes

```
public interface IRootService
{
    IChildService[] ChildServices { get; }
}

public class RootService : IRootService
{
    public RootService(IChildService[] childServices)
    {
        ChildServices = childServices;
    }

    public IChildService[] ChildServices { get; private set; }
}

public interface IChildService
{
    Component3 Component3 { get; }

    Component2 Component2 { get; }

}

public class ChildService: IChildService
{
    public ChildService(Component2 comp, Component3 comp3)
    {
        Component2 = comp;
        Component3 = comp3;
    }

    public Component3 Component3 { get; set; }

    public Component2 Component2 { get; set; }
}

public class Component3
{
    public Component3(Component2 comp)
    {
        Component2 = comp;
    }

    public Component2 Component2 { get; set; }
}

public class Component2
{
    private Guid _guid = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```